# How to fix Python error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymqe'

Tags: python, pymqi

I got the 9.3.4.0-IBM-MQC-Redist-Win64 and unzipped under C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ.
I was able to successfully install PYMQI via pip install, however, when I run my Python code, it throws the following error:

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pymqe: The specified module could not be found.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymqe'

I have pymqi-1.12.10 installed.

All system variables are properly defined on Environment Variables, for INCLUDE, LIB and MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.